# For XML Path from different tables.

Tags: sql, xml, select

I have the following script that can generate an XML for one table. I need to modify this slightly so that it pulls it from 3 different tables in one XML query. I am not sure how to modify this so that it does it in 1 query. Should I just create a stored procedure.:

```
SELECT 
CAST(EmployeeNumber AS varchar(9)) AS [employee/id], 
LastName AS [name/last], 
FirstName AS [name/first], 
'Employee' AS [persontype], 
email AS email
FROM dbo.Employees AS sd
WHERE (IsActive = 'Y') FOR XML PATH('employees')
```

The other table is:

dbo.Contractors

The query for that is slightly different:

```
SELECT 
CAST(EmployeeNumber AS varchar(9)) AS [employee/id], 
LastName AS [name/last], 
FirstName AS [name/first], 
'Contractor' AS [persontype], 
email AS email
FROM dbo.Employees AS sd
WHERE (IsActive = 'Y') FOR XML PATH('employees')
```

and the last one is:

dbo.Interns

```
SELECT 
CAST(EmployeeNumber AS varchar(9)) AS [employee/id], 
LastName AS [name/last], 
FirstName AS [name/first], 
'Intern' AS [persontype], 
email AS email
FROM dbo.Employees AS sd
WHERE (IsActive = 'Y') FOR XML PATH('employees')
```

Only field that changes is line 5 here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help :

```
select * from (
 SELECT 
 CAST(EmployeeNumber AS varchar(9)) AS [employee/id], 
 LastName AS [name/last], 
 FirstName AS [name/first], 
 'Employee' AS [persontype], 
 email AS email
 FROM dbo.Employees AS sd
 WHERE (IsActive = 'Y') 
 union
 SELECT 
 CAST(EmployeeNumber AS varchar(9)) AS [employee/id], 
 LastName AS [name/last], 
 FirstName AS [name/first], 
 'Contractor' AS [persontype], 
 email AS email
 FROM dbo.Employees AS sd
 WHERE (IsActive = 'Y'
 union
 SELECT 
 CAST(EmployeeNumber AS varchar(9)) AS [employee/id], 
 LastName AS [name/last], 
 FirstName AS [name/first], 
 'Intern' AS [persontype], 
 email AS email
 FROM dbo.Employees AS sd
 WHERE (IsActive = 'Y')) employees
 FOR XML PATH('employees')
```

Comment: +1: I'd suggest using `UNION ALL` for better performance (`[persontype]` is different from each UNION branch, so there should be no duplicates anyway) and some indentation for readability.

Comment: Yes you're right about performance, but these queries can't have duplicates because of the 5th line which has explicit value

Comment: i think that would work, I meant to put from different tables but didn't specify the tables in the queries... It's monday after all :)

Comment: @Pavel Yes, that's my point.  If you use `UNION`, it will sort or hash them to try to make them distinct.  So for best performance, you need to tell it not to do that by using `UNION ALL`.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you can't `UNION` these three queries? That will treat the 3 seperate queries as a single dataset.